# How to pass a Div id as a parameter to a C# function?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a `div` with an id and i want to activate a function (code behind) with the `div` id when someone click on the `div`.
help please?

Project .aspx.cs

```
        HtmlGenericControl Div1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        Div1.Attributes.Add("class", "ProjectItem");
        Div1.Attributes.Add("id", p.groupCode);
        Div1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about the `runat="server"` tag of the DIV

Comment: i dont understand you

Comment: it you add runat="server" to the div - <div id="something" runat="server"> </div> than you can see it on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way of doing it is adding a hidden server button to your page.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnPostback" style="display:none" onclick="serverEventHandler" />
```

And then add this to your div init:

```
Div1.Attributes.Add("onclick","document.getElementById('" + btnPostback.ClientID + "').click()");
```

And then add this to your code behind:

```
protected void serverEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Put code here
}
```

**EDIT:**
I don't see any proper way of sending the Div id, but you can change the hidden button's text to the Div id and then read it on the click event:

```
Div1.Attributes.Add("onclick","document.getElementById('" + btnPostback.ClientID + "').value='Div1';document.getElementById('" + btnPostback.ClientID + "').click()");
```

And the click event:

```
protected void serverEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string div_id=btnPostback.Text;
}
```

Comment: thank you Omer, it works fine, but how can i send the div ID attribute through the button to C# function as an argument?